# Jmeter jtl report not printing exception errors

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

Execute JMeter script file in non GUI mode and I am encountering a **java.io.IOException:**

When I try to load the script file. JMeter log file clearly reports this error and I understand what the error is and how to fix it.

Why is the JMeter jtl report not printing this exception error? When a script passes or fails then I see the appropriate result in jtl file.

Is there a way to write to this report?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter log is the log of the application and jtl file is just used to store **Sampler** results, see [Sample Result Save Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_configuration):

> Listeners can be configured to save different items to the result log files (JTL) by using the Config popup

Meaning in order to see it in jtl file you must attach this exception to a sampler, In case you find exception you can send the exception in a Sampler, for example [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/).